# Appsync Fine Graine Control on Mutation with Multiple Tables

Tags: aws-appsync

I have the following schema where the author of an Event can make notes on the Event. Only the author of the event should be able to create notes. I store the `author` in the Event. However, I'm finding other users are able to create a note on an event they didn't author by simply passing the eventId of an another users event, like so:

```
mutation {
  noteOnEvent(input: { eventId: "***", content: "A comment"}) {
    eventId
    content
  }
}
```

How can i prevent this? I don't see a way to access the EventTable author to in the `noteOnEvent` resolver

**Schema**

```
type Note {
    eventId: ID!
    notetId: ID!
    content: String
    author: String

}

input CreateNoteInput {
    eventId: ID!
    noteId: String!
    content: String
}

type Event {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    author: String 
    notes: [Note]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a **Nested Resolver**.

If you modify your schema slightly, you can accomplish it like so:

```
type EventCheckedNote {
  // Add a resolver on note which creates the note. The event will be available as $cxt.source, and you can make an authZ check before making the mutation.
  note: Note
}

type Mutation {
  // Add a resolver on noteOnEvent which queries the Event table.
  noteOnEvent(input: CreateNoteInput!): EventCheckedNote
}
```

Here is a tutorial on using nested resolvers to perform authorization checks with multiple data sources involved: https://hackernoon.com/graphql-authorization-with-multiple-data-sources-using-aws-appsync-dfae2e350bf2

Comment: Thanks @michalwillingham , what would the resolvers look like ? That’s the confusing part

Comment: oh @Michael-Willingham how to i access the original input arguments to create the note in the note.Note resolver? . They keep coming through as empty

Comment: If the original input arguments aren't available via $ctx.arguments in the child resolver, you could try returning a map of the input arguments in the parent resolver's response mapping template. Then, the note.Note resolver can access the data returned by the parent resolver via $ctx.source.{YourInputArgument}. Here is the documentation for the resolver context: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html